# Code Coverage Visual studio- Namespace not appearing in instrumented assembly

Tags: mstest

I have written few Unit test using MStest in visual studio and trying to generated the code coverage for the instrumented assembly which i have marked in the test settings. Although i am getting the code coverage for all  of the namespaces in the assembly but one. Is there a setting i need to make to make this namespace appear in the codecoverage window.

Comment: Did you instrument the assembly that the namespace is in?

Comment: Sorry but lost track of the same, coming back with the same problem.Yes i did instrument the same with the namespace in it.